# JQuery and Ajax - Refreshing on post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've got a page called Parent which contains a div called wfbdy.
On the Parent page, I have a number of links which update the contents of the wfbdy div using an AJAX calls as follows:

```
$('#wfbbdy').load('details/' + 1); or
$('#wfbbdy').load('details/' + 2);
```

Within the details page I have a form which contains a number of task items.
I'm using a combination of datepickers and the blur event to detect if a user exists a field. If this happens, I'm using an AJAX function to POST the data back to the server as below

```
    var $form = $("#ProcessID").parents('form');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            //handle this later
            alert('error');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            //handle this later

        }
    });
```

That works without issue.
The problem is, I have a timestamp associated with each Task in the details frame. This is sent across with the POST and I check to make sure it's greater than the modified date on the record in the DB.
I'm not sending this back to the page though so subsequent changes to the Task record send the origin modified date and it rejects the record.

How should I go about getting the modified date back into the hidden field?
Or alternatively, should I look to refresh the entire DIV after the POST so the modified dates are updated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

send the modified date back and handle it in the success function:

```
 success: function(response) {
        $("#myHiddenTimeStamp").val(response);
    }
```